# writing text on canvas again and again using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing JavaScript. I have insert Image on canvas and with another function I have put text from text box to canvas image by button click. but now problem is this if i enter different text in textbox and click button again and again it over writes text again and again. I want previous text should clear and new text come on the Image. I do not want to clear Image. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

A few options

1. Overlay the text in another element and just update that
2. Clear and redraw the relevant portion of the canvas (requires you keep a history of all drawing commands)
3. Convert to SVG

Canvas only holds the raster state of the drawing.  It has no concept of order or sub-elements.  The first is likely the easiest but hard to tell without knowing what you are doing.